# @IBDesignable fails to render class instance and crashes agent with Swift 3

Tags: swift, cocoa, xib

I have an xib which loads perfectly well after building the project. At build-time though I get the following error:

`Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render instance of PalitraPaletteSelector: The agent crashed`

I've read a lot of answers, even cleaned the DerivedData folder to no avail. Both initializers are implemented so I don't see what I'm missing here.

Here's the code I have:

```
@IBDesignable
class PalitraPaletteSelector: NSStackView {

    @IBOutlet var view: NSStackView!

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        loadViewFromNib()
    }

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        loadViewFromNib()
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PalitraPaletteSelector", owner: self, topLevelObjects: nil)
        view.frame = self.bounds
        self.addSubview(view)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use `Bundle.main` in a designable view. How about using `Bundle(for: type(of: self))` instead.

Comment: Well thanks so much man! It did work with the only exception that `self.dynamicType` was deprecated. The correct syntax was `Bundle(for: type(of: self))`.

Comment: Oops, sorry for my mistake. I've fixed my answer. And glad to hear it now works.